# Why does JMeter always show me a 0 ms latency when using 3rd party COAP Plugin?

Tags: jmeter, latency, coap

I'm testing an application running on a Raspberry PI via Apache JMeter. Everything works fine but JMeter always return 0 ms latency, no matter how many clients concurrently probe the Raspberry in the time unit.

At beginning I thought this behaviour was due to the short path between the client (my laptop) and the server (the raspberry) as they were on the same subnetwork in my house; then I decided to purposely add a delay on the server application (on the raspberry) before it answer (5 seconds to be precise); the responses were in fact delayed but latency was always 0. I searched on the web and many other users had the same problems but I found nothing that could be useful.

My requests are CoAP messages. I used a Plugin found at https://github.com/starrlingo/jmeter-iot-lib.
I tried several before this but they all gave me the same problem

Comment: https://ibb.co/mHyD5M1

(The server acts like a proxy but it doesn't matter what it does)

Comment: You need to specify you are talking about `CoAP JMeter Plugin`

Comment: Sure it is a Plugin Problem? I tried several before this and they all gave me the same problem. Anyway, what do you need to know?

Comment: if answer is ok which I think is the case, you should accept answer and upvote so that others can trustfully use the answer. Thanks

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK How can you say that the plugin I'm using does not set latency by calling that function if at  https://github.com/starrlingo/jmeter-iot-lib only the .jar file is available? Anyway I've already tried the plugin you suggested but I experienced other kinds of problems that led me to discard it.

I'll make another test with your plugin (perhaps I made a mistake in loading it the first time) and then I will accept the answer.

(PS. It is pleonastic underlying that the plugin in JMeter is a 3rd party one since JMeter does not support CoAP Protocol "natively")

Comment: If you read answer, the plugin you use has its source in the links and nowhere they call latencyEnd so latency is 0. We didn't suggest any plugin.

Comment: I do not understand you.
I use this: github.com/starrlingo/jmeter-iot-lib
You tell me to see this: https://github.com/emqx/coap-jmeter/blob/master/coap-jmeter/src/main/java/net/xmeter/samplers/CoAPPubSampler.java

Why they should be the same? Explain better yourself

Answer (score 0):

The plugin you're using does not set latency by calling:

- [SampleResult#latencyEnd()](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/trunk/src/core/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.java#L1320)

See:

- https://github.com/emqx/coap-jmeter/blob/master/coap-jmeter/src/main/java/net/xmeter/samplers/CoAPPubSampler.java
- https://github.com/emqx/coap-jmeter/blob/master/coap-jmeter/src/main/java/net/xmeter/samplers/CoAPSubSampler.java

Thanks @user7294900 for finding source code of your plugin

Comment: It seems that plugin sampler source is located https://github.com/emqx/coap-jmeter/tree/master/coap-jmeter/src/main/java/net/xmeter/samplers and doesn't call `latencyEnd()`